# openCV cameracalibration process

Tags: c++, opencv

According to http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/calib3d/camera_calibration/camera_calibration.html ,

"with calibration you may also determine the relation between the camera’s natural units (pixels) and the real world units (for example millimeters)."

could someone explain specifically how this is done? I think I understand the reprojection error calculated by the calibratecamera function. If I calibrate the camera with a pattern at an unknown distance from the camera, how do I use the reprojection error to then take that camera someplace else and perform measurements on objects at different unknown distances using the camera matrix or other information obtained using the calibration functions?

Answer (score 0):

If you pass the coordinates of the object points using some meaningful units (cm, mm, m instead of the usual "hey, it's some kind of grid" representation), you will find that rvect and tvecs are filled with the information that allows you to place the calibration patterns used in the process in metrically correct 3D space. But this is possible only because there is some prior information on the physical dimensions of the object you observe, as you're dealig with the monocular case. This additional information is used to impose proper scale on the scene you observe. One possible (and pretty simple) way to get the 3D position and orientation of an object is to use the [solvePnP](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#solvepnp) function or its RANSAC-driven version. Not sure about the details of your application, so I'll stop here.